# Graphhopper local instance travel time

Tags: graphhopper

I have local install of graph hopper. We use that for getting travel time between point A to point B.

in local instance how is the travel time computed by graphhopper? I know it uses OSM image but is the travel time returned is based on some historical time data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the open source routing engine there are [some heuristics](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.10/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/util/CarFlagEncoder.java#L111) based on maximum speed, road type and more to calculate the average speed estimate for a street.